# clang: stripping class names from the output

Tags: c++, clang, debug-symbols, clang++

I build a C++ project of mine using `clang++`, using the following command line command (split into lines):

```
clang++
  -std=c++11
  -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-newline-eof -Werror
  -O4
  -I<dirs>
  -L<dirs>
  -l<libs>
  -framework <frameworks>
  -D <defs>
  -o <filename>
  <files>
```

However, when I run `strings <filename>`, several class names show up, despite the `-O4` in the command line. I've tried `-Wl,-s` which should tell llvm to strip all symbols, but that doesn't remove these.

The class names that show up seem to all have one thing in common: they have a vtable. One of these classes is :

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual void myFunc() = 0;  
};
```

It shows up as the symbol :

```
N9namespace7MyClassE
```

I don't like it that my namespace and class names show up in the final file. How do I strip these? My binary is a command line utility, so only the `main` function should be exported.

---

Even after supplying `-fno-rtti` (as suggested by @n.m.), some names still remain, such as :

```
__ZN15MyClassInstance6myFuncEv
```

(MyClassInstance being a subclass of the MyClass above)

Additionally, even the names of global variables are in the binary.

Comment: Windows or Linux? On linux, I'd run "strip myprog" to remove all symbols [that aren't needed for shared libraries]#

Comment: What about [`strip`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/strip.1.html) with the `-S` and `-x` options?

Comment: Mac, actually. I tried `strip` but that didn't do anything. It looks like `-O4` implies `-Wl,-s` which executes `strip`. When I build with `-O3` a lot more class names show up, so I have to assume that clang is already doing a very good job stripping class names, it simply forgot a few.

Comment: You will have to at least disable RTTI. If your program relies on RTTI, you cannot get rid of these strings without source-level obfuscation.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that did it! Please add it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Actually, no, some symbols still remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by supplying the clang argument `-fno-rtti`, which disables RTTI, a C++ feature I don't use anyway.

[edit]
It looks like `-O4` does not imply `strip`, and the last few references to my class names can be removed by executing `strip`.